# Algo de errado com o if no controller Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

Tenho uma função em um controller do laravel, a princípio ela parece estar funcionando bem mas, quando passa pela parte do "if" pula direto para o "else", eis o código que está no controller:

```
//Inserção de troca(transicao) e decremento na tabela toner
public function printerInsert(Request $request){

    $oldsheet = printerChange::latest('folhas')
        ->where('marca', $request->marca)
        ->where('modelo', $request->modelo)
        ->where('toner', $request->toner)
        ->where('marca_toner', $request->tonerMarca)
        ->first();            

    $pageCount = printerChange::latest('folhasnew')
        ->where('marca', $request->marca)
        ->where('modelo', $request->modelo)
        ->where('toner', $request->toner)
        ->where('marca_toner', $request->tonerMarca)
        ->first();          

    $printerChange = new printerChange;
    $printerChange->setor = $request->setor;
    $printerChange->marca = $request->marca;
    $printerChange->modelo = $request->modelo;
    $printerChange->toner = $request->toner;
    $printerChange->marca_toner = $request->tonerMarca;
    $printerChange->data = $request->dataTroca;
    $printerChange->folhas = $request->folhas;            

    if($pageCount->folhasnew > 0){
        $printerChange->folhasnew = $request->folhas - $oldsheet;
    }
    else{
        $printerChange->folhasnew = $request->folhas;
    }

    dd($printerChange);

    //Decremento toner
    $printerSub = printer::where('modelo', $request->toner)
        ->where('marca', $request->tonerMarca)
        ->first();

    $printerSub->quantidade = $printerSub->quantidade - $request->quantidade;
    $printerSub->data = $request->dataTroca;

    //Save nas tabelas
    $printerSub->save();
    $printerChange->save();

    return redirect()->to('/printer');
}
```

Eu com certeza devo ter feito algo errado, só não consegui descobrir o que ainda, alguém pode me dar uma ajuda?

A é, o BD é postgres, não sei se influencia mas...

Eis as informações que resultam do dd($pageCount);:

```
printerChange {#223 ▼
  #table: "transicao"
  #primaryKey: "idtransicao"
  +timestamps: false
  +increment: false
  #connection: "pgsql"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:9 [▼
    "idtransicao" => 14
    "data" => "2018-12-06"
    "setor" => "Administrativo"
    "marca" => "Brother"
    "modelo" => "DCP-J125"
    "toner" => "PRETO"
    "marca_toner" => "J.PROLAB"
    "folhas" => 456654
    "folhasnew" => null
  ]
  #original: array:9 [▼
    "idtransicao" => 14
    "data" => "2018-12-06"
    "setor" => "Administrativo"
    "marca" => "Brother"
    "modelo" => "DCP-J125"
    "toner" => "PRETO"
    "marca_toner" => "J.PROLAB"
    "folhas" => 456654
    "folhasnew" => null
  ]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #fillable: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▼
    0 => "*"
  ]
}
```

Agradeço imenso desde já.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basta você trocar o seu if:
de

```
 if($pageCount->folhasnew > 0){
    $printerChange->folhasnew = $request->folhas - $oldsheet;
}else{
    $printerChange->folhasnew = $request->folhas;
}
```

para

```
if(is_null($pageCount->folhasnew)){ 
    $printerChange->folhasnew = $request->folhas - $oldsheet->folhas; 
}else{ 
    $printerChange->folhas = $request->folhas; 
}
```